# batch file for docplex

Tags: python, docplex

I have a mathematical model written in docplex python. For analysis, I have to generate different sized data with batch file which can be input for the problem. How can I generate this type of batch file?

Comment: Would you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555685/batch-file-size-limiter)?